# Why is this Postgres query on pg_type and pg_attribute table truncating the text?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create typescript types inferred from the database schema. So I want to iterate over all the custom type in the database to create a typescript type definition. However when I try to do it with one `case` statement to handle both composite and domain types, it truncates the composite types.

Here is a minimal reproduction without anything specific to typescript.

```sql
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS my_type CASCADE;

CREATE TYPE my_type AS
    ( attribute1 TEXT
    , attribute2 TEXT
    , attribute3 TEXT
    , attribute4 TEXT
    , attribute5 TEXT
    , attribute6 TEXT
    , attribute7 TEXT
    , attribute8 TEXT
    , attribute9 TEXT
    , attribute10 TEXT
    , attribute11 TEXT
    );

CREATE DOMAIN my_domain AS my_type;

SELECT
    CASE
    WHEN t.typtype='d' THEN (
        SELECT base.typname FROM pg_type base WHERE t.typbasetype=base.oid
    )
    WHEN t.typtype='c' THEN
        array_to_string
            ( ARRAY (
                SELECT a.attname || ': ' || at.typname
                FROM pg_attribute a
                LEFT JOIN pg_type at ON a.atttypid = at.oid
                WHERE t.typrelid = a.attrelid
                AND a.attnum > 0 
                )
            , ','
            )
    ELSE ''
    END
FROM pg_type t
WHERE typname='my_type' OR typname='my_domain';
```

Which outputs:

```
"case"
"attribute11: text,attribute10: text,attribute9: text,attribute8"
"my_type"
```

As you can see, the row for the composite type has been truncated. Could anyone explain to me the mechanism?

If I remove the look up for `typbasetype` it no longer has an issue:

```sql
SELECT
    CASE
    WHEN t.typtype='d' THEN (
        'HELLO'
    )
    WHEN t.typtype='c' THEN
        array_to_string
            ( ARRAY (
                SELECT a.attname || ': ' || at.typname
                FROM pg_attribute a
                LEFT JOIN pg_type at ON a.atttypid = at.oid
                WHERE t.typrelid = a.attrelid
                AND a.attnum > 0 
                )
            , ','
            )
    ELSE ''
    END
FROM pg_type t
WHERE typname='my_type' OR typname='my_domain';
```

It then outputs:

```
"case"
"attribute11: text,attribute10: text,attribute9: text,attribute8: text,attribute7: text,attribute6: text,attribute5: text,attribute4: text,attribute3: text,attribute2: text,attribute1: text"
"HELLO"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `pg_type.typname` is `name`, which constraints its values to 63 bytes:

```
=> \dT name    
                       List of data types
   Schema   | Name |                 Description                 
------------+------+---------------------------------------------
 pg_catalog | name | 63-byte type for storing system identifiers
```

The [rules to determine the result's  datatype](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-union-case.html) of the CASE statement say that when the type of the first branch of the CASE is not unknown and the other branches can be implicitly cast into that type, then it's chosen to be the type of the expression. So the overall result's type here is `name` and the values from the second branch of the CASE are truncated to 63 bytes.

One way to avoid that is to cast the first branch of the CASE into `text`:

```
CASE
WHEN t.typtype='d' THEN (
        SELECT base.typname::text FROM pg_type base WHERE t.typbasetype=base.oid
    )
...
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel! That worked great and make total sense. Very appreciated.